# How to align MathJax equation within the below code?

Tags: mathjax

How can I align the below Equation left or right using the below code?

[mathjax url="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"]
MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax:{inlineMath:[['$','$'],['\(','\)']]}});
[/mathjax]

$$x=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is really what you are after, but you can specify how displayed equations are aligned using the `displayAlign` configuration option, and can specify an indentation with `displayIndent`.  E.g.,

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  displayAlign: "left",
  displayIndent: "2em"
})
```

would get you displayed equations that are aligned 2em from the left-hand side of their containers.  Perhaps that will do what you want.